# jCaptcha - Refresh only image not whole page

Tags: captcha

I'm using jCaptcha (http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/) on our website.  The problem is sometimes it's very difficult to read the image. So, we are planning to provide a button named 'REFRESH' next to the jcaptcha image and upon clicking REFRESH button, it has to refresh only the jcaptcha image not the entire page/portlet. How can we do that?

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it using JQuery, it will replace the image. The alert() is just there to show off the new filename and can of course be removed. The code is using the jquery plugin in grails but shows what to do in jquery to refresh the image.

```
<div>
<jcaptcha:jpeg name="captchaImage"/>

<a href="#" id="refreshCaptcha">Refresh captcha</a>
<jq:jquery>
   $("#refreshCaptcha").click(function() {
      $("#captchaImage").fadeOut(500, function() {
         var captchaURL = $("#captchaImage").attr("src");
         captchaURL = captchaURL.replace(captchaURL.substring(captchaURL.indexOf("=")+1, captchaURL.length), Math.floor(Math.random()*9999999999));
         alert(captchaURL);
         $("#captchaImage").attr("src", captchaURL);
      });
      $("#captchaImage").fadeIn(300);
});
</jq:jquery>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make this changes in JSP :

```
<img src="jcaptcha" id="captcha_image"/> <a href="#" onclick="reloadCaptcha()" alt="reload"width="40" height="40">Refresh</a>
```

Add the Javascript function like :

```
function reloadCaptcha(){
        var d = new Date();
        $("#captcha_image").attr("src", "jcaptcha?"+d.getTime());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to load the image and the refresh button into . Than you should be able to refresh just the iframe. But the I don't know how you are performing your validation so.

Answer (score 0):

Set an id for the img tag and let it call a javascript function:

```
<img src="jcaptcha.jpg" id="captchaImage"/>
```

javascript function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() 
    {
        var captchaImage=document.getElementById("captchaImage");
        captchaImage.src="jcaptcha.jpg";    
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine because i implemented this one in my project just create one button on clicking that button it will come to below menctiond block of code like that you do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh() 
{
var image=document.getElementById("kaptchaImage");
image.src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/kaptcha.jpg?"+Math.floor(Math.random()*100)           
}
</script>
```